# Syntax error in from clause - no reserved words DA.fill

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, ms-access-2010

Having some issues with the myDataAdapter.fill line, getting the error "syntax error in From clause" looked around at other solutions and none have worked, most seem to be about reserved words - all out of ideas, help!

```
 'retrieve the connection string from the ConnectionString Key in Web.Config
        'string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Woof.mdb"
        Dim myDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet("Email")

        'create a new OleDB connection
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        'pass the Select statement and connection information to the initializxation constructor for the OleDBDataAdapter
        Dim myDataAdapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Email FROM Email-list", conn)



        'Fill the dataset and table with the data retrieved by the select command
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Email")
        Dim str As String = myDataSet.ToString


        Label3.Text = str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query

```
 Dim myDataAdapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Email FROM [Email-list]", conn)
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much. would you mind explaining why?

Comment: In any database system , if there is any space or underscore or any special char in table name or in case of any reserved keywords we use escape identifier i.e. square brackets "[ ]"

Comment: Excellent, for an encore would you mind telling me how i can convert the dataset to a string separated by commas? at the moment I'm playing around with SELECT COUNT and a loop but with no luck

Comment: you want to concate email addresses seprated with commas?

Comment: @deeps This question has been answered. If you have another issue then please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).